# Integrating Question with U-Sub: $\int\frac{\sin^3x}{\sqrt{\cos x}}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

## Question:

Find the value of the expression $$\int\frac{\sin^3x}{\sqrt{\cos x}}\ dx$$ by using the substitution $u=\cos x$.

## My Working:

If $u=\cos x$, then

\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dx}&=-\sin x\\
du&=-\sin x\cdot dx\\
\int\frac{\sin^3x}{\sqrt{\cos x}}\ dx&=-\int\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt{\cos x}}\cdot(-\sin x\cdot dx)\\
&=-\int\frac{1-\cos^2x}{\sqrt{\cos x}}\cdot(-\sin x\cdot dx)\\
&=-\int\frac{1-u^2}{u^{-\frac{1}{2}}}\cdot du\\
&=-\int u^{\frac{1}{2}}-u^{\frac{5}{2}}\cdot du\\
&=-\frac{2}{3}u^\frac{3}{2}+\frac{2}{7}u^{\frac{7}{2}}+c\\
&=-\frac{2}{3}(\cos x)^\frac{3}{2}+\frac{2}{7}(\cos x)^{\frac{7}{2}}+c
\end{align}

However, my teacher says that I got this question wrong, and that the answer was

$$-\frac{2}{3}(\cos x)^\frac{3}{2}-\frac{2}{7}(\cos x)^{\frac{7}{2}}+c$$ and that I made a mistake. Could anyone please tell me why I got the question wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made mistake while substituting in terms of $u$.

$\begin{align}-\int\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt{\cos x}} (-\sin xdx) &=-\int\frac{1-u^2}{\color{red}{u^{+1/2}}}du = -\int(u^{-1/2} - u^{3/2})du\\
&=-\frac{1}{1/2} u^{1/2} + \frac{1}{5/2} u^{5/2} + c\\\\
& = -2 (\cos x)^{1/2} +\frac25 (\cos x)^{5/2}+c\end{align}$

---

If the question were $\begin{align}\int{\sin^3x}\sqrt{\cos x} dx\end{align}$, then the result you've got is correct

$\begin{align}- \int{\sin^2x}\sqrt{\cos x} (-\sin xdx)&=-\int(1-u^2)u^{1/2} du = -\int (u^{1/2} - u^{5/2})du \\&= -\frac23 u^{3/2} + \frac27u^{7/2} + c\\\\
& = -\frac23 (\cos x)^{3/2} +\frac27 (\cos x)^{7/2} + c \end{align}$

Comment: Hi, did you make a mistake because $\frac{1}{u^{1/2}}=u^{1/2}$? Just double checking. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, $\frac{1}{x^a} = x^{-a} \rightarrow \frac{1}{u^{1/2}} = u^{-1/2}$

Comment: Oops, my bad. $0-1/2=-1/2$

Answer (score 1):

Using integration by parts, we simplify the evaluation as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{\sin ^3 x}{\sqrt{\cos x}} d x&=-2 \int \sin ^2 x d(\sqrt{\cos x}) \\
&=-2 \sin ^2 x \sqrt{\cos x}+4 \int \sin x \cos x \sqrt{\cos x} d x \\
&=-2 \sin ^2 x \sqrt{\cos x}-4 \int \cos ^{\frac{3}{2}} x d(\cos x) \\
&=-2 \sin ^2 x \sqrt{\cos x}-\frac{8}{5} \cos ^{\frac{5}{2}} x+C
\end{aligned}
$$